# Is it possible to pass parameters to angular factory

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular resource factory and I would like to know if it is possible to pass path/query parameters to the factory function. Please see the comment in the code snipped to get a better clue.

```
.factory("$Sentiments", function($resource, d3Service, ??URL-Parameters??) {
        var d3 = d3Service;
        var result = {};
        var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                .size([100, 100])
                .value(function (d) {
                    return d.activity + .35;
                })
                .sort(function (a, b) { 

                    // < ------------- HERE ---------- >
                    // I would like to sort based on a query parameter like so:
                    // if url is like http://localhost/#!/lala?sort=asc

                    return a.activity - b.activity != 0
                        ? a.activity - b.activity
                        : a.symbol < b.symbol ? -0.01 : 0.01;
                });
```

Comment: Why don't you create a function within the service that takes the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect URL parameters in the factory by injecting $location and using it methods to parse the URL like this:

```
var sort = $location.search().sort;
```

Then you can use that variable to do your logic.

Answer (score 0):

as factory is a singleton instance, you better just return a function which accepts parameters,

like:

```
.factory("$Sentiments", function($resource, d3Service) {
    var d3 = d3Service;

    return function(??URL-Parameters??){
         var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
            .size([100, 100])
            .value(function (d) {
                return d.activity + .35;
            })
            .sort(function (a, b) { 

                // < ------------- HERE ---------- >
                // I would like to sort based on a query parameter like so:
                // if url is like http://localhost/#!/lala?sort=asc

                return a.activity - b.activity != 0
                    ? a.activity - b.activity
                    : a.symbol < b.symbol ? -0.01 : 0.01;
            });
}
```